# Does Removing items from SelectedItems source remove them from the ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, selecteditem

If I had 2 `ObservableCollections<someObject>` one represents the `ItemsSource` and one represents the `SelectedItems` source.

Does calling the `Clear()` function on the `SelectedItems` source remove those items from the `ItemsSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it would just affect your `SelectedItems` collection (by emptying it of course). `Clear` just removes items from a collection not another one :

- `ItemsSource` references an `ObservableCollection` containing object references.
- `SelectedItems` references another `ObservableCollection` containing some objects references also contained into your `ItemsSources` collection;

Calling `Clear` method on your `SelectedItems` collection will only removes object references contained in `SelectedItems`, not objects (themself) or object references from another collection (here `ItemsSource`).

Comment: so to remove each item in my SelectedItems from my ItemsSource i need to loop? thats what i am trying to achive

Comment: Yes you would need to find the corresponding items in your ItemsSource collection and remove them.